Trouble Importing Flutter Packages
I'm having issues when importing Flutter packages. Whenever I add a package, like "audio-file," to my pubspec.yaml and run pub get, it works fine. However, after a cold start, the app breaks completely.
I run flutter clean
I run pub get
I try upgrading the package to the latest version

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Okay here is the error message i get while building. "Unknown Kotlin JVM target:21"
